# How to prove the p-adic expansion of negative p-adic integers ends with p-1?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I just started calculating with p-adic numbers and one of the questions I'm stuck on is how I can prove that for a negative integer the p-adic expansion ends with an infinite amount of digits p-1. I tried to check it with some examples like $-1 = ...(p-1)(p-1)(p-1)$ and $-2 = ... (p-1)(p-1)2$ and so on. I tried proving it with induction on $n$, but I don't see how I can complete the induction step. I thougt about $-n = -(n-1)-1$, but I'm confused with how I can add these up to see $-n$ again ends with $p-1$.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Actually, I think your $p$-adic expansion of $-2$ is incorrect. For $p>2$ its last digit should be $p-2$, not $2$.

Comment: $r+(-r)=0$. If $r$ is a positive integer, then its $p$-adic expansion is finite, so for the $p$-adic expansion of $r+(-r)$ to be all zeros, once you run out of digits of $r$, you must have to "carry the one" forever after, adding it to $p-1$ in the expansion of $-r$. So the expansion of $-r$ must end with an infinity of $p-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Case 1 in the proof of Theorem 3.1 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/rationalsinQp.pdf).

For a self-contained description, first look at what an infinite $p$-adic expansion is when all of its digits are $p-1$ and it starts in position $p^d$:
$$
\sum_{k \geq d} (p-1)p^k = (p-1)\frac{p^d}{1-p} = -p^d.
$$

With this in mind, when $n$ is a negative integer, pick $d$ so large that $-p^d < n < 0$.  Then $N := p^d + n$ has $0 < N < p^d$, so when we write $N$ in base $p$ its digits will involve nothing higher than $p^{d-1}$:
$$
N = c_0 + c_1p + \cdots + c_{d-1}p^{d-1}
$$
where $0\leq c_i \leq p-1$.  Then
$$
n = N - p^d = c_0 + c_1p + \cdots + c_{d-1}p^{d-1} - p^d = c_0 + c_1p + \cdots + c_{d-1}p^{d-1} + \sum_{k \geq d} (p-1)p^k.
$$

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

(Edit: Replaced earlier answer with different approach.)

Your expansion of $-2$ is incorrect. I would think if you see the expansions of negative numbers, you'll see what is happening. Let's take $p=5$ for example, then

$$-1 = ...44444444$$
$$-2 = ...44444443$$
$$-3 = ...44444442$$
$$-4 = ...44444441$$
$$-5 = ...44444440$$
$$-6 = ...44444434$$
$$-7 = ...44444433$$
$$-8 = ...44444432$$
$$-9 = ...44444431$$
$$-10 = ...44444430$$
$$-11 = ...44444424$$
$$\dots$$
$$-24 = ...44444401$$
$$-25 = ...44444400$$
$$-26 = ...44444344$$
$$\dots$$
See how you will not run out of $4$'s on the left.